# Python web scraping returns error

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am currently learning Python and have tried to pick up web scraping. I have been using example code that I got from some tutorials, but I have encountered a problem with one of the sites I was looking at. The following code was supposed to return the title of the website:

```
import urllib
import re
urls = ["http://www.libyaherald.com"]
i=0
regex='<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    titles=re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print titles
    i+=1
```

The title for Libya Herald website returned back an error. I checked the source code for Libya Herald and the DOC TYPE is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`.

Does the doc type have something to do with me not being able to scrape from it?

Comment: Regexp is completly not suitable for web scraping, you will be much better of with xpath. Also there is magnitude of tools that will make your process much easier to manage and run, for example http://scrapy.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crawler only loads one title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308357/crawler-only-loads-one-title)

Answer (score 0):

As @Puciek said, with regex is gonna be very difficult to scrape html. I would recommend you start using some package, a very easo to use and install is [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Once you install it you can try this simple example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('http://www.libyaherald.com').text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)

title = bs.find('title').text
print title
```

Answer (score 0):

For serious python web scraping I strongly suggest [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

And as far as I know, when it comes to html parsing, regex is not a recommended way. Try BeautifulSoup (BS4) like Pizza guy said :)